# How to use Python Lepl to parse a subset of a domain specific language?

Tags: python, parsing, lepl

I'm using Lepl as a parser and the language I'm parsing is very complicated and I only care about a small subset.  I can't figure out a way to have Lepl parse the grammar I care about and just return strings for everything else.  If I add a rule like:

```
everything_else = ~newline & Regexp('.')[:]
```

Then it gets used instead of the things I care about.  I think it is happening because it is a longer match than my other rules.  Is there a configuration setting or something in Lepl so that I can have an imperfect parser?

**Update**
As requested adding some details.  I only want to parse out the top level variable definitions that equal a number.  The ones that are dependent on others or are a math expression I want to ignore.  I also want to ignore what is inside the block definitions There are many other constructs in the language that I want to ignore.  So here's an example:

```
from lepl import *

class Variable(List): pass
import string

def parse_it(a_string):

    # Parser:  TODO: incomplete
    s = ~Space()[:] # zero or more spaces
    s1 = ~Space()[1:]  # 1 or more spaces
    newline = Newline() & s
    number_squote = ~Optional(Literal("'")) & s & Real() & s & ~Optional(Literal("'"))
    number_dquote = ~Optional(Literal('"')) & s & Real() & s & ~Optional(Literal('"'))
    number = number_squote | number_dquote | Real() >> float
    var_keyword = ~newline & ~Regexp(r'(?i)variable')
    var_name = Word() >> string.lower
    var_assignment = s1 & var_name & s & ~Literal('=') & s & number > Variable
    vars = var_keyword & var_assignment[1:]
    parser = vars[1:]
    return parser.parse(a_string)

input="""
VARIABLE abc=5 bbb='7' ddd='abc*bbb'
variable ccccc=7  // comment
block(1,2,3,4) of_type=cleaner abc=4 d=5 c=string('hi')

define_block block2 (3,4,5,6,7,a,b) var1=35 var2=36
variable ignore_this=5
block3(3,4,5,6) x='var1*ignore_this' y=var2
block4(4,5,6,7,a,b) x='var1*2' y="var2*3"
end_block

block2(1,2,3,4,5,6,3) abc=ccccc d=abc 

create_blocks  // comment: initialize memory
connect_blocks // connect blocks together
simulate // 

"""
for i in parse_it(input):
    print i
```

So I only really care about the `variable Word() = Real()` information in the file defined outside the block definitions.  I want to keep the rest as strings so that I can build a AST and modify the variable values and then write out the control file again.

Comment: can you give more details?  how would you expect to find the part you care about?  could you put the rest of your code in pastebin (or post on the lepl mailing list)?  in general, lepl does things in the order they are given, but the matcher above will consume *everything* after the newline.  one solution might be to use the tokenizer, if it is easy to tokenize your language (unfortunately, it often isn't easy).

Comment: Since lepl is no longer maintained, maybe a move to pyparsing is in order

Comment: @PhilCooper: I'm open to alternatives.  I just thought Lepl was the best thing out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, if i understand correctly, you want to parse any line that starts with "variable" (ignoring case) and that is not inside a block.

the first thing we need to worry about is how much we need to understand about the bits we want to skip.  for example, we could skip everything between `define_block` and `end_block`, but what if the text "end_block" happens to appear in some string?  maybe to handle that case we also need to be aware of strings?  or comments?  these kind of worries are why often it is not as easy as you might think to simply skip text - it turns out that to understand what we can skip we actually *do* need to parse the data.

but perhaps in this case we are ok.  it looks like you have neither multi-line strings not multi-line comments, and that `define_block` and `end_block` always occur at the start of a line.  that gives us enough guarantees (i think) to be able to drop blocks without worrying about strings or comments (because a string or comment would start with `//` or `"` or similar, and so a misleading  `//define_block` or `"define_block"` would not be at the start of the line).

we can do that outside of lepl:

```
block = re.compile(r'^\s*define_block.*?^\s*end_block[^$]*', re.I | re.M | re.S)
input = block.sub('', input)
for line in input.split('\n'):
    if line.lower().startswith('variable'):
        print line
```

or as a regexp inside:

```
block = Regexp(r'(?ims)^\s*define_block.*?^\s*end_block[^$]*')
```

so your final solution will be something line

```
variable = ...
other_line = Regexp(r'^.*$')
parser = (variable | block | other_line)[:]
```

hope that helps.

and finally, full disclosure, i should also point you to https://groups.google.com/group/lepl/browse_thread/thread/e305b5b559d93e9e which i posted today (sorry).

Comment: Thanks for the post.  You answered my question but made me nervous about using Lepl.  It sure seems like a great tool from a newbie point of view.  Can you recommend an alternative?

Comment: the "standard" (most popular, not official) package for simple parsing in python is pyparsing.  i am not a great fan (which is one reason why i made lepl) but it has a much bigger community than lepl and you will get much more support/help from them.  for more complex parsing, i think the most popular library is antlr.

Comment: After looking at pyparsing it isn't a recursive decent parser...kind of limiting if you are parsing a domain specific language.  I am pretty happy with Lepl and your small works well.  In Lepl can you parse the `block` and use a recursive definition to add hierarchy to the AST?  I want the `variable` inside the `block` in the AST.  I tried to define a block having `variable` or `other_line` but it runs away with 100% CPU.

Comment: sure, lepl can do that.  i thought pyparsing was recursive descent?  odd.  anyway, the usual reason lepl spins cpu is because you are repeating an empty match (so it matches nothing, repeats, matches nothing, repeats, ...).  typically this happens when you have `foo[:][:]` (although it not so easy to see as the two `[:]` may not appear together in the code).

Comment: expanding on the above, `foo[:]` matches 0 times, consuming no text, and then is repeated indefinitely by the outer repetition.  the way to fix is usually to change the inner `[:]` to `[1:]` so that `foo` must consume some input.

Comment: That worked for me.  Now this is slick!  I tried to use  pyparsing but Lepl is more powerful.  So I plan to use it for this pet project until someone comes out with a better replacement.